# Ideablade and RemoveEntity

Tags: c#, winforms, devforce

I have a problem. I click Add in my app and i grab the next id number and create an object using that id number as the key. If the user changes their mind, they click Discard. I remove the entity from the cache using RemoveEntity(myobject) method and i place the id number which is unused back to be used again. The user clicks Add again and gets the same id number. When i try to add the newly created object to the entity cache, it gives me an error that an object with that entity key already exists in the cache. My Question is, Why doesn't RemoveEntity remove it from the cache and how do i add a new object into the entity cache using the same id number? I can't clear the cache as there may be other objects in the cache needed by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found the answer. I was removing the object wrong. I changed the order of my code lines and it now works.